# java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service

Tags: android, android-activity

I know there are few similar threads out there I have tried them all, none of them seem to work for me. I'm trying capture Screenshots in Android  but unfortunately It keeps crashing and giving me this error. In AndroidMaifest.xml the name is in red as if it's not getting recognised.

```
public class ScreenshotAction extends SinglePressAction {

private static Context mContext;
private String mScreenshotLabel;
private Drawable mScreenshotIcon;
private static final Object mScreenshotLock = new Object();
private static ServiceConnection mScreenshotConnection = null;

public ScreenshotAction(){
    super();
}

public ScreenshotAction(Context context, String screenshotLabel, Drawable screenshotIcon) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    mScreenshotLabel = screenshotLabel;
    mScreenshotIcon = screenshotIcon;
}

@Override
protected void setupLabel(TextView labelView) {
    labelView.setText(mScreenshotLabel);
}

@Override
protected void setupIcon(ImageView icon) {
    icon.setImageDrawable(mScreenshotIcon);
}

@Override
protected void onPress() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            takeScreenshot(handler);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "screenshot ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

public static void takeScreenshot(final Handler mHandler) {
    synchronized (mScreenshotLock) {
        if (mScreenshotConnection != null) {
            return;
        }
        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.systemui",
                "com.android.systemui.screenshot.TakeScreenshotService");
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(cn);
        ServiceConnection conn = new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                synchronized (mScreenshotLock) {
                    if (mScreenshotConnection != this) {
                        return;
                    }
                    Messenger messenger = new Messenger(service);
                    Message msg = Message.obtain(null, 1);
                    final ServiceConnection myConn = this;

                    Handler h = new Handler(mHandler.getLooper()) {
                        @Override
                        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                            synchronized (mScreenshotLock) {
                                if (mScreenshotConnection == myConn) {
                                    mContext.unbindService(mScreenshotConnection);
                                    mScreenshotConnection = null;
                                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mScreenshotTimeout);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    msg.replyTo = new Messenger(h);
                    msg.arg1 = msg.arg2 = 0;
                    try {
                        messenger.send(msg);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {}
        };

        if (mContext.bindService(intent, conn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)) {
            mScreenshotConnection = conn;
            mHandler.postDelayed(mScreenshotTimeout, 10000);
        }
    }
}

private static final Runnable mScreenshotTimeout = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (mScreenshotLock) {
            if (mScreenshotConnection != null) {
                mContext.unbindService(mScreenshotConnection);
                mScreenshotConnection = null;
            }
        }
    }
  };
}
```

Error:-

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: ......, PID: 6022
              java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { cmp=com.android.systemui/.screenshot.TakeScreenshotService }
                  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1595)
                  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1559)
                  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:517)
```

AndroidMaifest.xml

This name is in red which tells me that it doesn't recognise it.

```
<service android:name=".screenshot.TakeScreenshotService"
        android:process=":screenshot"
        android:exported="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying capture Screenshots in Android

Use the media projection APIs on Android 5.0+.

> It keeps crashing and giving me this error

You do not have rights to bind to that service. You do not even know if that service exists on any given device.

> This name is in red which tells me that it doesn't recognise it.

That is because you did not write that service.

Comment: The above needs to be working on 4.4.4 at the moment it works on 4.2.1 but crashes on 4.4. +  any suggestions ?

Comment: @Tony: Either do not offer screenshots, or only offer screenshots on API Level 21+ (Android 5.0+), using the media projection APIs. There is no supported means of programmatically requesting system screenshots prior to Android 5.0.

Comment: Thank for teh advice. The trouble is that there is another party who have developed an app using similar code to what I have posted and on teh same hardware and Android version their app works. I have a version of the app using code as above that works on a Android 4 device, but only on that one, and crashes with teh above error on the others. It seems that there might be a library or permission that is set on one device but not on the others in relation to this app/code. I have added some debug to log package permissions to logcat with this code runs to see if that sheds light.